# Get entry from the database and add it to a new excel file using Spreadsheet Excel writer in php doesn't work, why?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, spreadsheet

I admit to have asked this questions already around 4-5 hours ago but because I got no reply I deleted it and ask again hoping there is someone able to help me now... I hope this is okay... Thank you! :)

I have a problem; I can get an entry from a database, I can create an excel file using spreadsheet excel writer but apparently I can't do both as a combination; Here my script to get an element of a database:

```
<?php

require ('config123.php');


            $sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_123, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


echo $row['name'];

?>
```

This works great; Also to create an excel file with some entry is no problem:

```
<?php

require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';
$excelfile = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

$excelfile->send('excelfile.xls');

$worksheet =& $excelfile->addWorksheet('Tabelle 1');


$worksheet->write(1, 1, 'blub');

$excelfile->close();

?>
```

I can open the excel file and everything works great; But once I try to combine it, it doesn't work out anymore:

```
require ('config123.php');
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';
$excelfile = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

$excelfile->send('excelfile.xls');

$worksheet =& $excelfile->addWorksheet('Tabelle 1');


            $sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_123, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

$worksheet->write(1, 1, 'blub'); // notice that I don't even write the value from the database in it but just a word and it still doesn't work

$excelfile->close();

?>
```

To be more precisive it gets problems from the two require options; Those must somehow conflict theirself although I don't know how... The excel document is being created but excel can't open it anymore and inside it's full of many error messages; 
I already changed names in my config123.php file hoping that there are just 2 varaible names with the same name but unfortunately it didn't help;
This is how my config123.php looks like:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

define ( 'MYSQL_HOST',      'localhost' );

define ( 'MYSQL_BENUTZER',  'root' );
define ( 'MYSQL_KENNWORT',  '' );

define ( 'MYSQL_DATENBANK', 'database' );

    $db_123 = mysqli_connect (
                 MYSQL_HOST, 
                 MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                 MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                 MYSQL_DATENBANK
                );

    if ($db_123 === False) {
        die("<p> Es konnte keine Verbindung mit der Datenbank hergestellt  
 werden </p>");
    }


?>
```

I can't open the excel file normally where I actually only wanted to write 'blub' inside, however I can open the file with the normal windows editor and get this(it may help):

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method OLE::Asc2Ucs() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\Spreadsheet\Excel\Writer\Workbook.php** on line **575**

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method System::tmpdir() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\OLE\PPS\File.php** on line **50**

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method System::tmpdir() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\OLE\PPS\Root.php** on line **56**

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method OLE::Asc2Ucs() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\OLE\PPS\Root.php** on line **59**

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method OLE::LocalDate2OLE() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\OLE\PPS.php** on line **190**

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method OLE::LocalDate2OLE() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\OLE\PPS.php** on line **191**

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method OLE::LocalDate2OLE() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\OLE\PPS.php** on line **190**

**Deprecated**:  Non-static method OLE::LocalDate2OLE() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in **C:\xampp\php\pear\OLE\PPS.php** on line **191**
ÐÏà¡±á                ;  þÿ                                 þÿÿÿ       ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

```
        þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ       l    ÉB  ä       Tabelle 1=      ¼%r8      X"    1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È   ÿ      Arial1  È         Arialà      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à      õÿ  À       à          À       à        À       “  € ÿ’ â 8     ÿÿÿ ÿ    ÿ    ÿ ÿÿ  ÿ ÿ  ÿÿ €    €    € €€  € €  €€ ÀÀÀ €€€ ™™ÿ ™3f ÿÿÌ Ìÿÿ f f ÿ€€  fÌ ÌÌÿ   € ÿ ÿ ÿÿ   ÿÿ € € €    €€   ÿ  Ìÿ Ìÿÿ ÌÿÌ ÿÿ™ ™Ìÿ ÿ™Ì Ì™ÿ ÿÌ™ 3fÿ 3ÌÌ ™Ì  ÿÌ  ÿ™  ÿf  ff™ –––  3f 3™f  3  33  ™3  ™3f 33™ 333 …  -      Tabelle 1
   l    É     *    +   €          ‚      Á      ƒ    „    &        è?'        è?(        ð?)        ð?¡ "   d       XX      à?      à?  
        blub>
```

¶
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           R o o t   E n t r y                                               ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ            À      F     fé\Ñ fé\Ñ   @      B o o k
  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ       À      F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              þÿÿÿ      þÿÿÿþÿÿÿýÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

Any idea how to solve it???? :(

Comment: You appear to be mixing up APIs. That's not going to work, Stick with mysqli (or PDO) all the way through.

Comment: Can you tell it a little bit more precisely? I am a beginner unfortunately... :( I know I tend to mix it but what do I need to replace in this example? :)

Comment: Well, you're calling the following functions 'statically' but that method appears to have been deprecated:

Asc2Ucs() 
tmpdir() 
LocalDate2OLE()

Comment: So what do I do best to avoid it? :)

Comment: Instantiate an object and call the method from that object. You may be able to suppress the warnings by changing `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to something like `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: Well I will try that, thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Dear people from the future who are still using the PEAR Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package:

These errors are caused by the PEAR OLE package, more specifically version 1.0.0RC2. One way to fix this is to force downgrade the OLE package to RC1:

```
pear install -f OLE-1.0.0RC1
```

For those also getting the "Call-time pass-by-reference" error, that can be fixed by manually updating the code as suggested here:
http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19359

In Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Worksheet.php on line 2490 change:

```
$this->_append(&$string, true);
```

to:

```
$this->_append($string, true);
```